# How to link User model and User profile between schemas in django?

Tags: django, postgresql, foreign-keys, schema, django-migrations

I am trying to build a multi-tenant application using django-tenant-schemas. I have successfully created the tenant and custom user model. I want all of the user's to be globally authenticated but create their profile inside the tenant they are associated with.

I have included the userProfile model inside the tenant apps. The user accounts are created successfully but upon receiving signals to create a profile(one-to-one related), it throws an error.

Can any one help me on this, please? Can I maintain the foreign-key constraint across schemas ?

Comment: can you show your error traceback ?

Comment: It throws django.db.utils.ProgrammingError stating, it can't find userProfile_user Profile table. https://imgur.com/SWkxqt3

Comment: @PragyanAryal That's all 3rd party code. Something in your code must be involved in the stack trace. Copy the whole lot out of the console & add it to your question so that we can see what's being executed & throwing the error in your code.

Comment: Maintaining a foreign key across the schema is not possible. For global authentication issues package like **django_tenant_user** comes handy.